# implications of difference between RMS and mean in rectified and non rectified graphs

Tags: signal, rectifier, signal-processing, rms

I have a project relating to EMG signals and i did a full wave rectification to zero for the graphs before calculating mean and RMS of the graph. My question is, would it make more sense to find the mean of the rectified graphs and the RMS of the non rectified graphs to compare. If so, what would the difference between the mean and RMS values show or imply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is, would it make more sense to find the mean of the
>   rectified graphs and the RMS of the non rectified graphs to compare.

The basic lack of understanding here is that you will find: -

RMS(unrectified) = RMS(rectified)

The squaring process (i.e. the "S" in "RMS") ensures that after squaring both waveforms are identical.

So, the RMS of a rectified signal is exactly the same as the RMS of an unrectified signal.

As a footnote, the average of a rectified signal does not equal the RMS of that signal.